# Editing NPM packages from forked github repo

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack

It happen that I have to modify one of the package I use inside my `package.json` unfortunatley project does not approve any PR at the moment so I forked the repo and edited `package.json` to

```
"dependencies": {
    ....
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "https://github.com/Mixeway/ng2-smart-table.git",
    ....
}
```

in `ng2-smart-table` project I have edited one of the file (regarding problem with filtering of nested objects) and pushed it to my repo.

ATM when i try to run my project I get:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/ng2-smart-table/projects/ng2-smart-table/src/lib/lib/data-source/local/local.data-source.ts
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js): Error:
>   C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules\ng2-smart-table\projects\ng2-smart-table\src\lib\lib\data-source\local\local.data-source.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Format
>   (...).
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:913:23)
>       at C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31
>       at runMicrotasks ()
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/ng2-smart-table/projects/ng2-smart-table/src/lib/ng2-smart-table.module.ts
>   Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js): Error:
>   C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules\ng2-smart-table\projects\ng2-smart-table\src\lib\ng2-smart-table.module.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Format
>   (...).
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:913:23)
>       at C:\Users\gsiew\IdeaProjects\MixewayFrontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31
>       at runMicrotasks ()
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

could anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Note that what they [publish](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/package.json#L13), the package you actually install, is the *result* of the build. If you require from the TS source, you'll also need to include that in your compilation.

Comment: ehh I thought it would be easy.. So if I understand You I should publish the package to npm into some other name and then use it in package.json?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you'll need to do *something* other than just use the source code as a dependency. All of `node_modules/` is excluded from compilation by default.

Comment: Here is the easy way. Modify the project(Better check the license) and keep a local version in your source control. Build the package locally, which will produce a tar file in `dist` directory. Then you can install it in your project via `npm i <path_to_local_package>/dist/<package_name>/<tar_file>`.

Comment: but I need it to be used remotely -  by travis during npm install and docker image build..